# Use of not in command with find in set

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE user_id NOT 
IN (
 FIND_IN_SET( user.user_id,  '1,2,3,4,7,8,21,42,12' )
)
```

But its not working fine ,when the series is in continue then only it print the id not present 
ex. as 1,2,3,4 is in continuous this ids are only not present in my result but i want the complete list not present in my list.

I am calling  function in find in set
SELECT user_id
    FROM user
    WHERE user_id NOT 
    IN (
     FIND_IN_SET( user.user_id,  block_id(1) )
    )
it gives me the string of comma separated values and when i pass the string 
ex WHERE user_id NOT 
    IN (
     '1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9'
    )
it ignore only the first value
so please help

Comment: there is no need for find in set here use not in only, see my answer below for reference

Comment: @MURTUZA007 i think you got your answer so why don't you selected your answer yet,is that you need something more or what?

Comment: no i don't get the answer i have edited my question please check it and give me a feedback

Comment: @MURTUZA007  remove '' from NOT IN ( '1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9' )  like not in (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9) and tell if it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE user_id NOT 
IN ( 1,2,3,4,7,8,21,42,12 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand what `FIND_IN_SET` does -- this function gives you the *position* (or index rather) of the search value. So if `user_id` was = 7, it would return 5. This would basically make your SQL function useless because you are comparing a single user id with indices and it would equate to:

Given a user_id = 7:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE user_id NOT 
IN ( 5 )
```

Comment: but how could i fulfill the above condition

Comment: Give this a shot: `SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,7,8,21,42,12);` should give you all user_id's except those in your list. If I misunderstood your question and you want to continue the series, that would be more challenging to program and you wouldn't be able to do it using SQL alone...